# Using dataSource property with List<Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> _DictionaryList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("Max", "Berlin");
dictionary.Add("John", "New York");
dictionary.Add("Mike", "London");
dictionary.Add("Tedd", "Miami");

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary2.Add("cat", "Milk");
dictionary2.Add("dog", "Meat");
dictionary2.Add("llama", "Water");
```

I need to display view like this:

[image]

I use asp.net `DetailView` control to display data above, I want to use `DataSource` property of `DetailView` control.

But the problem is If I use this:

```
DetailView1.DataSource = _DictionaryList;
DetailView1.DataBind();
```

I don't get the desired view,I get displayed only the number of of items in dictionary and dictionary2.

My question is how can I make desired view (as in images above)?

Comment: what are you getting now?

Comment: @MethodMan `_DictionaryList` is a list, so it doesn't have a `Values` property.

Comment: `DetailView1.DataSource = _DictionaryList.SelectMany(d=>d.ToList())`?

Comment: @juharr he's not even populating `_DictionaryList` so there is also a problem in itself..

Comment: Your best best is to use a  `Repeater` control. DetailsView is for displaying a single record from a data source and not for what you are trying to accomplish. Or you could also use a GridView control since you want to a tabular layout.

Comment: @Sunil , What is the problem with DetailView control? I need to display single item per page.

Comment: @techspider, I get displayed only the number of of items in dictionary and dictionary2.

Comment: @Michael, I think it would be more straightfoward to use a repeater or gridview control rather than a DetailsView. The normal use of a DetailsView is to display a single record.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind a Dictionary as a DataSource to any data control.  You may need to convert to a List or dynamic object.

Comment: Can you please show example?How do I convert example Dictionary above to dynamic object or List?

Comment: there are many articles... try http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-dictionary-list

Comment: You actually _can_ bind a dictionary (it is an `IEnumerable`). You just need to `Eval()`

Answer (score 0):

I was just curious to mimic the output of the posted screenshot.

**The markup (aspx):**

```
<div style="width: 250px">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterInfo" OnItemDataBound="ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrInner" ClientIDMode="Predictable">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table style="width:250px; text-align: left;">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%#Eval("Value") %></td>
                        <td><%#Eval("Key") %></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrFooter" ClientIDMode="Predictable">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemIndex") %>' Font-Bold='<%#Eval("ShouldHighlight") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

**The code-behind:**

```
private List<Dictionary<string, string>> _DictionaryList;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Max", "Berlin" }, 
        { "John", "New York" }, 
        { "Mike", "London" }, 
        { "Tedd", "Miami" }
    };

    var dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "cat", "Milk" },
        { "dog", "Meat" }, 
        { "llama", "Water" }
    };

    _DictionaryList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
    {
        dictionary, 
        dictionary2
    };

    repeaterInfo.DataSource = _DictionaryList;
    repeaterInfo.DataBind();
}

 protected void ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var innerRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("rptrInner") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater;
        var footerRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("rptrFooter") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater;

        innerRepeater.DataSource = _DictionaryList[e.Item.ItemIndex];
        innerRepeater.DataBind();

        footerRepeater.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, _DictionaryList.Count).Select(i => new { ItemIndex = i, ShouldHighlight = e.Item.ItemIndex + 1 == i });
        footerRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Output page:

[image: browser output of the markup + code]